# Why Facebook Likes Blocked in My URL? I'm Not a Spammer

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-like, blocked

good morning!

Since last week my website URL - www.musiconline.xpg.com.br - and others sites from www.xpg.com.br , is/are with the LIKE BUTTON blocked.

I need the solution for this problem Urgently, because I'm NOT a Spammer!!!

My Fan Page is with a problem too: http://www.facebook.com/musicasonline

I'm trying to talk with Facebook in Forum and Support, but I still have no answer until now.

Thanks a lot for all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook won't share a link to my site](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13185406/facebook-wont-share-a-link-to-my-site)

Comment: Facebook isn't blocking your site. Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: cpilko.. A year ago you talked my HTML was invalid. Where is the problem? Do you know? Thanks for help.

Comment: Take a look at the W3C validator: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.musiconline.xpg.com.br&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got my URL back.  Facebook blocked use of our URL for years, yes years. For some reason no one would include our website URL (a-fib.com) in any post, or even on our own FB page. They'd get an error message saying our site had been flagged as spammy. This had been going on for years! FB has zero customer service.

Here's what worked. After trying everything else over the course of three years, we finally resorted to writing a pleading letter on our letterhead, asking why would anyone block a non-profit trying to help heart patients? We sent it 'registered mail' to FB headquarters. (Advice I found among other ideas online from those with a similar problem.)  It worked. Praise the lord!

Comment: Hello! I sent a letter to Facebook (two letters) but I never received an answer. I sent in June, 2013. Would you mind to send here the correct address of Facebook HQ, please? Thank you very very much. My site it's still blocked > [http://www.musiconline.com.br](http://www.musiconline.com.br)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not care if you personally are a spammer or not – it just blocks the whole domain, in this case most likely xpg.com.br.

This is a risk you’re always taking when using a shared domain. To avoid it, the best way is to get your own domain – then it’s you and only you who’s responsible – whereas now, if one of the users on this domain does not behave, all other users of the same domain will get punished as well.

Comment: Hello, CBroe!Thanks for the answer, but the domain xpg.com.br is my Investor (helping me to Host the site). Nowadays, I need this subdomain musiconline.xpg.com.br . Well, me and XPG needs solution for this case, because some similar cases are solutioned.

Comment: Well, you can always appeal and try to get it unblocked … but don’t ask me right now where the forms/channels for set are, you’ll have to refer to their help section. (If you try to post a link to your domain as a user on facebook.com and get the message its blocked, you can appeal from right there I think.)

Comment: So, I sent a lot of messages to Facebook's Help and in the Forum, but I got only answers from Users, not Ffacebook Employees. well, thanks a lot, and I still continue searching for a solution.